# No /kivy drectory in SD card using Kivy Laucnher

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to run a Kivy app using the Kivy Launcher, however, when I connect my phone to the  computer and try to put the file containing the app there is no kivy directory in which to put my app.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy Launcher does not create that directory automatically, you have to create it. Launcher only opens that directory and search for `android.txt` files. If no such file is available, it won't display your project in Launcher's list, therefore you won't be able to run it.

Path is usually `sdcard/kivy`, but at least on samsung there is this little change `sdcard/0/kivy`, it only matters when you create if, because Launcher doesn't check literally for that path, rather it gets the path from android api.

More info in [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-your-application-for-the-kivy-launcher) and [code](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/b34371819401d131bd3f8e85767d35df527dce16/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/pygame/build/src/org/renpy/android/ProjectChooser.java#L39).